# Undefined method 'logout'. intelephense(1013) [18,17] Laravel 7 Logout Controller

Tags: laravel-7

I'm using Laravel 7 and Visual Code. My Logout Controller have a problem but the code work when i run. What's the problem?

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class LogoutController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Handle the incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function __invoke(Request $request)
    {
        auth()->logout();
        return redirect('/');
    }
}
```

Error in my VSCode is

```
Undefined method 'logout'. intelephense(1013) [18,17]
```

[image: Error Images]

It's a bug? or my fault? Thanks

Comment: Without sharing more details, it's close to impossible to provide help

Comment: Also, where did you define that method `auth()`? What does it return? I would assume that you are missing a proper type hint

Comment: im using solution in here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43087648/logging-out-via-a-link-in-laravel . They dont declare about auth( ) , It's a problem?

Comment: i remember, i dont use `php artisan make:auth` because i want to make my original controller, if i  use it, i cannt make original controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know about the error but i was fix it.

I change the code with

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class LogoutController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Handle the incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function __invoke(Request $request)
    {
        Auth::logout();
        return redirect('/');
    }

}
```

i assumed the code is false, and i was change it.