# Laravel Livewire logout button doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire, laravel-9

I have created a Laravel 9 application with Livewire and there I have a logout button which use `Auth::logout()` and redirect to the login page. I have set up everything correctly as I understand but the button doesn't work.

Function in `Profile.php`

```php
public function logoutUser() {

        Auth::logout();

        return redirect(route('auth.login'));

    }
```

Logout button in `profile.blade.php`

```html
<button wire:click="logoutUser" class="block px-4 py-2 mt-2 text-sm bg-white md:mt-0 focus:text-gray-900 hover:bg-indigo-100 focus:bg-gray-200 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline">Logout</button>
```

What is the issue here? TIA!

Comment: What happens when you click the button, exactly? I'm guessing it's a session issue, and that you should just make a POST request to a normal controller instead

Comment: @Qirel It does nothing actually. So you recommend to make a normal controller and logout using that.

Comment: Yes, because it'll have to destroy the session, and working with session in Livewire is difficult because they are api requests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Qirel recommended I used a regular controller instead of a Livewire controller to handle the logout. Followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49580579/16484935) for implement that correctly.